# How can I write a bash script that tells me how many hours there are from 23:43 to 02:10?

Tags: shell, date

How can I calculate with hours and minutes in bash? For example say I want to write a script that takes two timestamps and tells me how many hours there are in between them, how can I do that?

```
$ timediff 23:43 02:10
Time difference is: xxx hours.
```

How do I handle if the second timestamp is one day later, like in the example?

Comment: It will depend what day of the year you perform the calculation, and whether in the case of a one hour jump back your 02:10 is the first or second instance of that time. Also please consider whether you want to take account of the occasional leap second inserted at midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ t1="23:42"
$ t2="02:10"
$ e1=$( date -d "$t1" +%s )
$ e2=$( date -d "$t2" +%s )
$ if (( e1 > e2 )); then e2=$( date -d "$t2 tomorrow" +%s ); fi
$ date -d@$e1
Tue Oct  6 23:42:00 EDT 2015
$ date -d@$e2
Wed Oct  7 02:10:00 EDT 2015
```

To find the difference, if you don't need fractional hours, use shell arithmetic, otherwise pipe to `bc`

```
$ diff=$(( (e2 - e1)/3600 ))
$ echo $diff
2
$ diff=$( echo "scale=2; ($e2-$e1)/3600" | bc)
$ echo $diff
2.46
```